# Change UIWindow background color when device rotates

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewanimation, uiwindow

My `UIWindow` initially has a white background. I want to change the background to blue (permanently) when the device rotates. But what actually happens is the color briefly flashes blue then goes back to white.

In the app delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)oldStatusBarOrientation
{
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

This code gets called as expected, but when the rotation finishes, `-[UIWindow setBackgroundColor:]` gets called a second time (as I discovered by subclassing `UIWindow`). The call stack for the second call is:

```
-[UIWindow setBackgroundColor]
-[UIWindow _finishedFullRotation:finished:context:]
-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:]
-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:]
-run_animation_callbacks
...
```

**Edit (for @VinceBurn's answer)**

The application has exactly one view (from Xcode's View-based Application project template). I have now set the view's background color (in IB) to 0% opacity. Still getting the same results.

To make sure the white color is not coming from some other default color setting, I am now initially setting the window's background color to green:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Add the view controller's view to the window and display.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

When it rotates, it briefly flashes blue but returns to green.

Comment: Where and how do you initially set the white background?

Comment: @VinceBurn -- I have tried not setting it anywhere (white is the default), and I have tried setting it in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Same results either way.

Comment: @jlstrecker: Sorry, this was a bit quick and silly - please forget it. Sounds a little bit like bug. I just cam across UIView's animateWithDuration:animations. I haven't worked with it but maybe it's possible to implement it that way to get around the 2nd call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to change the background color of the active `UIViewController`'s view, instead of the `UIWindow`:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

The reason I had been trying to set the background color of the `UIWindow` was to get the same background color throughout the app. Apparently the simplest way to accomplish that is to have all `UIViewController`s in the app inherit from a `UIViewController` subclass that implements `-didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is a little bit better, but I still hope for something else.

```
- (void)changeColor 
{
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
willChangeStatusBarOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)newStatusBarOrientation 
                      duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
  //  At first set it to the color
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
  // And make it change again when the animation is finished
  [self performSelector:@selector(changeColor) 
             withObject:self 
             afterDelay:duration + 0.005];
      //  You may have to play with the add part of the duration this was working 
          in the simulator, but on device?
}
```

My guess is that under the hood the orientation is change through a CAAnimation, and the new property set in a CAAnimation don't stick at the end so you have to set them also out side the animation.

Comment: @jlstrecker That was so intriguing that I've tried it. And I can't fixe it. I've try register with the NSNotification for the change orientation, it the documentation it says that it's call later than the app delegate one. But still same result...

Comment: Tried your solution on a couple of devices (with a slightly modified app that turns green for portrait and blue for landscape.) The time to add to `duration` for devices is more like 0.2 or 0.25. As it turns out, the ideal time depends not only on the device, but also on the direction you're rotating (to landscape vs. to portrait), and on how many times you've rotated before! If the time is too short the color doesn't change, and if it's too long the color flickers after rotation. I'm going to try some other workarounds and if I end up using yours then I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: @jlstrecker if you find a better solution please post a little comment, I'm curious. Thanks.  I'm not sure exactly when you need the colour change, but I've seen in the doc that it can be animated, so if you make the time a little longer you could start an animation on that property after the rotation is completed... but probably not the effect you are searching.